# Изменить фон у Midnight Commander в PHPStorm (SSH Terminal)

Tags: phpstorm

Добрый день.

Может кто-то уже сталкивался, когда запускаю SSH Session и в терминале открываю Midnight Commander, то получаю серый фон, на котором не видно текста: 
[image: введите описание изображения здесь]
Подскажите пожалуйста, что в настройках PHPStorm 7 можно подкрутить, чтобы изменить цвет этого фона?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы изменить стандартную цветовую схему Midnight Commander, открываете
файл:

```
~/.config/mc/ini
```

или, если 1 пункт не сработал

```
~/.mc/ini
```

Создаете там секцию с примерно таким содержанием.

```
[Colors]
base_color=lightgray,blue:normal=blue,default:selected=white,brightblue:marked=yellow,default:markselect=yellow,gray:directory=brightblue,default:executable=brightgreen,default:link=cyan,default:device=brightmagenta,default:special=lightgray,default:errors=red,default:reverse=green,default:gauge=green,default:input=white,gray:dnormal=green,gray:dfocus=brightgreen,gray:dhotnormal=cyan,gray:dhotfocus=brightcyan,gray:menu=green,default:menuhot=cyan,default:menusel=green,gray:menuhotsel=cyan,default:helpnormal=cyan,default:editnormal=green,default:editbold=blue,default:editmarked=gray,blue:stalelink=red,default
```

И да, тут у вас какой-то странный эмулятор терминала из IDE. Возьмите что-нибудь нормальное вроде Konsole, rxvt, Yakuake.

Код выше создает новую цветовую схему прямо в конфигурационном файле. Однако есть еще несколько уже готовых схем. Чтобы получить их список и редактировать:

```
ls /usr/local/share/mc/skins
```

Чтобы установить добавьте опцию в основную секцию [Midnight Commander]:

```
skin=%название темы без расширения ini%
```

Либо запускайте mc с ключом S

```
mc -S skinname
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.
А перечисленные вами эмуляторы терминала: Konsole, rxvt, Yakuake - их можно как-то подцепить в PHPStorm 7?

Comment: А какой смысл в запихивании эмулятора терминала внутрь IDE? Мой мозг не в силах понять этого, так как это явно противоречит тому факту что каждая программа в *nix окружении крайне узко специализирована.

Comment: Просто вроде удобно не выходя из IDE что-то в консоли поделать. И еще вопрос по поводу цветов, все цвета в mc настроил через ~/.mc/ini , но когда открываю в нем на просмотр или редактирование файл F4, то у меня фон синий http://itmages.ru/image/view/2424525/1b830617

Не подскажите, как это исправить?

Comment: Там должна быть одна гигантская строка в секции colors, не нужно вставлять разрывы строк. Либо поставьте какую-нибудь еще тему. И да не заходите в ssh под рутом, это опасно. Используйте ключи или запрет авторизации для всех подсетей кроме своей в sshd_config, а также запрет root авторизации, иначе бессмысленный и беспощадный китайский брутфорс рано или поздно отберет у вас ваш хост.

Comment: Скрин, который показал - это не ~/.mc/ini , это другой файл открытый в  Midnight Commander через F4 и в нем проблема с фоном.
Т.е. что нужно дописать в ~/.mc/ini чтобы фон в редакторе стал прозрачным (черным)?